# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler()Lorg/quartz/Scheduler;

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm getting error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler()Lorg/quartz/Scheduler;
```

this is caused when 
    public class myJobLauncher {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myQuartzScheduler")
    private  SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler_factory = null;
.......
    ........
        Scheduler someScheduler = scheduler_factory.getScheduler();
```

and here are my xml files

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">          
 ....
 <bean id="myQuartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
 <property name="autoStartup">
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property name="name">
  <value>myScheduler</value>
</property>
<property name="quartzProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">1</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore</prop>
    <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
  </props>
</property>
  <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory" />
  </property>
```

not sure why i'm getting that exception

here is my pom file entries
    
        
            org.quartz-scheduler
            quartz
            1.8.6

using spring framework 4.0.0

added all spring-context-support,spring-context,beans,transaction.

we have some client code which is using above version of quartz  ,we are integrating their spring project and adding enhancements to it. so bottom line is we cannot modify their code  .

Comment: There's a good chance that the dependencies that were present when you compiled on your dev machine are not present on the computer giving the error.

Comment: i just did a clean and then did a install. ,and i could see these dependencies in my  local m2 repo. did i miss any?

Comment: Do you have the right version of everything installed?

Comment: here are the versions i have    quartz-scheduler quartz 1.8.6 ,spring framework  ,core ,beans ,transactions,context,context support,4.0.0 ,slfj -1.5.10.  let me know if i miss any

Comment: And you're sure that the java runtime environment is configured to know where you have those installed?

Answer (score 0):

i finally got around this issue.

i have included following explicitly in my pom file. i was under impression this will be automatically added as its used by Quartz.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>asm</groupId>
   <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
   <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also moved that Quartz configuration to separate xml file.